# Advanced filters ExtJS dataGrid?

Tags: forms, user-interface, datagrid, extjs, filtering

is there a way to do an advanced filter for a Ext js datagrid

something like this : 
[smartclient library advanced filter](http://www.smartclient.com/#filterBuilderBracket)

and many thanx

Comment: what's the result of your research. I'm trying to find something similar like it's in Smartclient. Did you find something or implement finally yourself? Thanks, qwx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a search plugin which will do search on all fields.  This can be setup as local or remote: http://gridsearch.extjs.eu/.

If you want similar filter as noted above, you can build a form, and process at the server end, and reload the grid.

Comment: the serach plugin is nice but it's not what am seeking , so am trying to do it by my self , thanks